# What causes an imported audio CD file to have silent gaps?

Tags: audio, sound-editing

I used Audacity to import an audio file from a CD and I see that the file has numerous silent gaps in it. Are these gaps from the original CD?      [image: screen shot of 1 gap in file]

Comment: Could be on the CD, could be read errors or timing errors. From just a picture of the waveform, no-one's ever going to know.

Comment: Don't you still have access to the original CD?

Comment: Yes I do have access to the original CD.

Comment: How did you import the file? Did you just grab the raw data or did you 'play' the CD into Audacity, or...?

Comment: I imported the track into Audacity from my hard drive after having added it into the iTunes library from the original CD.

Comment: Download and use a tool called EAC. Exact Audio Copy. If there are any errors on the import, EAC will show it up. CD importing on iTunes is too permissive and will not indicate any import errors.

Answer (score 1):

Was the original CD burned?  If so, alot of burning software like Nero or whathaveyou gives an option to insert a small gap between songs when burning the CD.  It used to bug me when I had both Tommy and The Wall burned like that from friends cause it would mess up the flow.  That might be the reason.  That or iTunes may have done this when ripping the CD - did you rip it to a single file or something?

Comment: I have decided that it must be a problem with the original CD...read errors or timing errors.